# Laravel 10, Vue3 and Inertia. Using form and router url issue appears

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a strange behavior using Inertia with Vue3.

I created a simple address book, in the create user there is the useForm, router from Inertia.
When I call them during to save the URL from addressBook/create change in addressBook/store so in case the user reload the page this goes in error because the method get for addressBook/store is missing.

My code is this:

**VUE Component**

```
form.post(route('addressBook.store'), {
    onSuccess: () => {modal.show(), form.reset()},
});
```

**Controller PHP**

```
public function store(StoreAddressBookRequest $request)
{
    AddressBook::create($request->all());
    return Inertia::render('AddressBook/create');
}
```

So the html page after the store is correctly AddressBook/create but in the URL it is changed in AddressBook/store.
The same happens if I use the router.post call.

Is there a solution?

Thanks, Roberot

Comment: What does your form and form handler look like?

Comment: form is a Inertia useForm 
import { useForm, router  } from '@inertiajs/vue3'; 
and it is 
const form = useForm({
  firstname: '',
  surname: '',
  birth: '',
  address: '',
  city: '',
  cap: '',
  email: '',
  phone: '',
});

Comment: You need to add more context to the question, as I already requested. Your current code doesn't explain what's actually going on.

Comment: I have not use `onSuccess` in `useForm` before but typically, when you run POST request, you either return `json response` or `redirect to index`. In your case, if you wish to redirect back to created, then `redirect to create route` + flash value. use flash value to trigger `modal.show(), form.reset()` if when opening create, these two methods are not executed at mounted.

Comment: Or return a `json response`, add a param `response` inside `onSuccess` (not sure if param is allowed) then use the response value to do something inside.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Thanks all for your feedback but the question was a little different.
usePost and router are Inertia modules that in background use axios but implementing it with several difference.

First of all the return in the controller is useless.

```
return Inertia::render('AddressBook/create');
```

I did not understand well but Inertia get back the result directly so for this reason the URL in web page does not change with the return Inertia render but use the route used in the form (or in the router).

The solution of this issue is this:

change the web.php route called addressBook.store using the url of the same actual page, in my case these routes:

```
Route::get('/addressBook/create',           'App\Http\Controllers\AddressBookController@create')->name('addressBook.create');
Route::post('/addressBook/store',           'App\Http\Controllers\AddressBookController@store')->name('addressBook.store');
```

in this way

```
Route::get('/addressBook/create',           'App\Http\Controllers\AddressBookController@create')->name('addressBook.create');
Route::post('/addressBook/create',           'App\Http\Controllers\AddressBookController@store')->name('addressBook.store');
```

Changing addressBook/store with addressBook/create, remove the return from the controller and all works fine

Comment: Just a note it might have worked with the original routes if you used `return to_route('addressBook.create);`